# How google maps know the certain roads are one/two way?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, arduino, gps, gsm

How to get information from google maps that roads are one or two way??
I need complete one or two way information of each roads in city and differentiate one way and two way roads using google maps.
I am doing project that GPS,GSM and arduino module attached to the vehicle has to identify the vehicle travelling in wrong way road if so,the module has to send wireless message containing data such has time,location of vehicle etc

what and all hardware and software required to perform above operation??

Comment: Not a task for an arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are no feature in Google APIs to determine whether the road is one way or not, however, you may file a Feature Request in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) of Google Maps Platform.